# Why Azure functions in a consumption plan can't have a vNet or a hybrid connection?

Tags: azure-functions

I'm curious if this limitation is regarding some kind of technical limitation that makes impossible to implement something like that or just a business decision regarding Microsoft Azure business goals?

Answer (score 3):

As per my understanding,

Consumption Plan is only true "Serverless" and the App Service Plan, Premium plans are not true "Serverless" environments.

Consumption Plan is like pay per use model completely which means pay when your function ran but the Premium and Dedicated Plans are predictable pricing as they have at least one pre-warmed instance and host will be running continuously.

One of the business scenarios in terms of usage and pricing is you can have multiple function apps with VNet Integrations in the same Premium hosting Function app plan where you will pay for the one i.e., app plan instance.

Adding Virtual Network Integration feature to the Azure Functions Consumption Hosting plan is still on open state and raised in the [Azure Official feedback site](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/d647e855-f224-ec11-b6e6-000d3a4f0da0) where many customers upvoting and requesting this feature in Consumption plan for variety of scenarios mentioned in the [GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/646#issue-286823032).

Comment: Update, a new "flex consumption" plan is currently in private preview per Microsoft's announcement here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/register-for-access-to-upcoming-azure-functions-flex-consumption/